# How to map millisecond precision timestamp field in MySql with JPA

Tags: jpa, timestamp, milliseconds

I need to store millisecond precision timestamp to database.

I made a lot of tries with things from google search. But every tries failed.
All of them truncated milliseconds and return only to the seconds.

What's wrong with my tries?

Here I list what I have tried.

// Environment

```
JPA 2.1
Hibernate 5.2.10
MySql 5.5.28
```

### // My Tries...

```
// Failed to get milliseconds
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date updatedAt;


// Failed to get milliseconds
private java.sql.Timestamp updatedAt;


// Failed to get milliseconds
@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private java.sql.Timestamp updatedAt;


// Failed to get milliseconds
@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP (3)")
private java.sql.Timestamp updatedAt;


// Failed to get milliseconds
@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP (6)")
private java.sql.Timestamp updatedAt;


// Failed to get milliseconds
// with converter https://github.com/leapfrogtechnology/vyaguta-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lftechnology/vyaguta/commons/jpautil/LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter.java
private LocalDateTime updatedAt;


// Failed to get milliseconds
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private org.joda.time.DateTime updatedAt;
```

Comment: Problem solved. It was mysql version issue. After upgrade latest 5.7 version. Everything works fine.